# Перенапровление на страницу с ошибкой при ограниченном limit_conn

Tags: nginx

Раздаю файл с помощью nginx (отдельным субдоменом отличным от основного сайта)в конфиге поставил лимит с помощью limit_conn равной единце.Из [документации](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_conn_module.html#limit_conn) понятно что в случае последующих запросов на скачивание файла сервер вернет 503 ошибку. Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать красиво так что бы юзера отправляло на страницу сайта с информацией о том что лимит достигнут и кодом страницы 200.

Есть идея добавить [limit_conn_status](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_conn_module.html#limit_conn_status) с ошибкой (307, например) и в обработке оной перенаправить юзера куда нужно. Но я не уверен в адекватности идею.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В конфиг

```
error_page   503  =  /503.html;
```

Где 503.html путь к файлу нужного содержания.

Ну в качестве бонуса можно так же сделать это в качестве локейшена:

```
location = /503.html {root /srv/http/errors;}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Все очень круто заработало :)